# Is context null going to new activity?

Tags: xamarin.android

**Goal**:

Call method from another activity and return a result from user input (popup)

**Problem**:

I am getting the following error
[image]

**What I've tried**:

Instantiating object before calling method
Creating intent and calling StartActivity as well as tried StartActivityForResult but this just goes to an blank screen. I did check the content view in the CveActivity.cs

**Activity1.cs**:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    PProfile pProfile = await DataUtility.GetPProfileAsync(SettingsValues.ApiURLValue, Token, global.UserInfo.PID).ConfigureAwait(false);
    CveCheckDTO respGetCve = await DataUtility.GetCveEligibilityForHomeViewDialogAsync(SettingsValues.ApiURLValue, mInfo.PID, Token).ConfigureAwait(false);

    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {                    
        CveActivity ca = new CveActivity();
        ca.ShowCveMInfo(pProfile.PID, respGetCve.IsCve);
    });
});
```

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem?  Could you please post a basic demo to github or onedriver and share the link here so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?